# HIBERNATE: How to use a varchar column with comma separated content as a list in an Entity

Tags: java, hibernate

How to use a varchar column as a list in an Entity??
And not persist like another table?
The content is comma separated.

```
....
@Column
private List<FlagChave> flags= new ArrayList();
....


CREATE TABLE "ENTITY"  (
      "ID" BIGINT NOT NULL , 
      "FLAGS" VARCHAR(255 OCTETS) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Entity:::

```
....
@Column
@Convert(converter = StringToListFlagConverter.class)
private List<FlagChave> flags= new ArrayList();
....
```

Class Converter.

```
@Converter
public class StringToListFlagConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<FlagChave>, String> {

  @Override
  public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<FlagChave> flagChaves) {
      if(!Optional.ofNullable(flagChaves).isPresent()) return "";
      return flagChaves.stream().map(FlagChave::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
  }

  @Override
  public List<FlagChave> convertToEntityAttribute(String joined) {
      if(!Optional.ofNullable(joined).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).isPresent()) return new ArrayList<>();
      return
              Arrays.asList(
                      joined.split(","))
                      .stream()
                      .map(FlagChave::valueOf).collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new)
              );
  }
}
```

Class enum.  I was created with an enum, but you can do with a String.

```
 public enum FlagChave {
  CHAVE,
  VALOR_PADRAO,
  CONDENSAR_LINHAS;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
      return super.toString();
  }
}
```